# Facebook Sharing in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I implemented Facebook sharing in my app.

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content=[[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc]init];
        [content setContentDescription:theDescription];
        [content setContentTitle:theTitle];
        //[content setContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:itemURL]];
       // content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developers.facebook.com"];
       [content setImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
    [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:self];
```

But the "Sharing" dialog shows empty. Why does it not show/post the title & description which I set?

Answer (score 0):

The text of the sharing view is not prefilled because Facebook does not let you do so. The content description & title is used when the link is displayed on Facebook, this is different from the sharing wording.

Comment: ok , thanks for your reply

but how to post only text? & why image is also not shown?

Comment: If link is display then Title & description will added from URL content 
not form programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Try that;

```
FBSDKShareDialog *shareDialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc]init];
[content setContentDescription:theDescription];
[content setContentTitle:theTitle];
[content setImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];

[shareDialog setMode:FBSDKShareDialogModeAutomatic];
[shareDialog setShareContent:content];
[shareDialog setFromViewController:self];
[shareDialog show];
```

Comment: wait... I am checking

Comment: I have edited also if it's still not working, change mode FBSDKShareDialogModeAutomatic to FBSDKShareDialogModeBrowser.

Comment: actually, I want native app
So I set `Automatic Mode` but not working

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this (Objective-C)? It's working fine in Swift for me:

```
func shareLinks(title:String, imageUrl:String, contentUrl:String, vc:UIViewController){
        var fbcontent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
        //Valid url that contains any content
        fbcontent.contentURL = NSURL(string: contentUrl)
        //Title of this post
        fbcontent.contentTitle = title
        //Image will be displayed in timeline with this post
        fbcontent.imageURL = NSURL(string: imageUrl)
        dialog.shareContent = fbcontent
        dialog.fromViewController = vc
        dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.Automatic
        dialog.show()
    }
```

Comment: also please do not add content URL & check
it will not work

Comment: try without content URL

Answer (score 0):

If  you share this

```
[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developers.facebook.com"];
```

Does Sharing dialog Shows empty?

If not  - you have to know that there have to be OPEN GRAPH information on page that you share.

For share picture use

```
FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
  photo.image = image;
  photo.userGenerated = YES;
  photo.caption=@"Some text";
  FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
  content.photos = @[photo];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but
I don't have link to share
I just have text & image to share

Comment: I you share image try this FBSDKSharePhoto

Comment: use photo.caption or  content.caption

Comment: it gives me error com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=photos must have UIImages

I try to set imageURL

Comment: did you have image on device? or only by Url?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SLComposer as an alternative

Answer (score 0):

For FBSDK 4.12.0 version:

Facebook link share work like this:

```
 FBSDKShareLinkContent *content =[[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
 content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:songUrl];
 content.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:artWorkURL];
 content.contentTitle= [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", trackName];
 content.contentDescription=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some text"];
 [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:self];
```